# Appindicator Icon Animation

Tags: indicator, gtk3, glib, pygi

I'm writing a software using `pygobject` for GTK+3 (Ubuntu 12.04, stable repo package versions for all dev tools) and I'd like my application to have animated `AppIndicator` icon.

It's easy to make `GLib.timeout` and emit `set_icon` signal every time frame changes.
But nevertheless `AppIndicator` icon is not redrawn immediately.

So the question is: "Is there any way to make `AppIndicator` icon force redraw?".

For now it redraws once per several seconds without any stable period or sometimes when mouse activates top panel widgets.

Comment: You could try the following two lines to make sure any GUI events are done: `while Gtk.events_pending(): Gtk.main_iteration()`